# If $x^*:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a linear map with $\dim(X)>1$, then there exists $x\in X$ with $x\neq 0$ such that $x^*(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: Let $X$ be a vector space. If $x^*:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a linear map with $\dim(X)>1$, then there exists $x\in X$ with $x\neq 0$ such that $x^*(x) = 0$.

Intuitively, I think the statement is true, as I always kernel of bounded linear functional as hyperplane.

If $\dim(F)=1$, then the kernel must be a straight line passing through origin.
In this case, the statement above is false.

For any $\dim(F)>1$, it seems that the statement holds.
But I do not know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: What, $\ker (x^*) \subsetneq \{0\}$? You mean to say that $\ker (x^*) = ∅$? You sure?

Comment: maybe the inclusion was meant to be the other way around

Comment: @alphaomega I figured.

Comment: @k.stm I edited my post.

Comment: With $X$ not being $ℝ$, I suppose you mean to say $X$ not being isomorphic to $ℝ$ (and not being $0$ either), that is: $\dim X > 1$. That has nothing to do with Banach spaces, dual spaces or functional analysis in particular. If $φ\colon X → ℝ$ is a linear map and $\dim X > 1$, then $φ$ always has a nontrivial kernel.

Comment: @k.stm I edited my post based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Any non-zero  continuous linear functional is surjective. If the kernel is $\{0\}$ then it is an isomorphism onto $\mathbb  R$. Hence $X$ is one-dimensional.

Proof of surjectivity: Choose $x$   such that $x^{*}(x) \neq 0$. If $r$ is any real number the $r=x^{*}(cx)$ where $c=\frac r {x^{*}(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to invoque the dimensions theorem, and in this case:

$$\dim\ker x^*+\dim\text{Im}\,x^*=\dim X$$

and since $\;\dim\text{Im}\,x^*\le1\;,\;\;\dim X>1\;$ , we get that

$$\;\dim\ker x^*\ge1\implies \,\exists\,0\neq x\in X\,\,s.t.\,\,x^*(x)=0\;$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are two perspectives that are slightly different from the answers already given.

Since $X$ is of dimension greater than $1$, we can find two linearly independent vectors $v,w\in X$.  If $x^*(v)=0$ or $x^*(w)=0$, then we are done.  Otherwise $x^*(x^*(v)w-x^*(w)v)=x^*(v)x^*(w)-x^*(w)x^*(v)=0$.

Alternatively, by the first isomorphism theorem, $\operatorname{im}(x^*)\cong X/ker(x^*)$, and since $\dim(\operatorname{im} x^*)\leq 1$ and $\dim X > 1$, we must have that $\ker(x^*)$ is nontrivial.